# How can i call the JavaScript anonymous function using Golang and V8Go?

Tags: javascript, go, v8

The JavaScript file: [Javascript File](https://github.com/mmaico/code-on-demand/blob/master/src/main/resources/js-code/json-mask.js)

In Java i call this function using this code:

```java
public class JavaScriptEngine {

    private ScriptObjectMirror mirror;
    private Object eval;

    public JavaScriptEngine() throws IOException, ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        /**
         * Use the line below to load the file directly from a CDN, this is recommended to get new versions automatically
         * Object eval = engine.eval("load('https://cdn.com/json-mask.js')");
         */
        String absolutePath = new File("src/main/resources/js-code/json-mask.js").getAbsolutePath();
        Object eval = engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(absolutePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        this.mirror = ((ScriptObjectMirror) ((ScriptObjectMirror) eval).get("default"));
        this.eval = eval;
    }

    public String call(String field, String type) {
        String json = "{\"value\": \"" + field + "\" }";
        String setting = "[{\"type\": \""+ type.toUpperCase()+ "\", \"path\": \"$.value\"}]";
        Object aDefault = mirror.call(eval, json, setting);
        Object read = JsonPath.parse(aDefault.toString()).read("$.value");

        return read == null ? null : read.toString();
    }

}
```

But i need call this function with GoLang and this lib [V8 Go](https://github.com/rogchap/v8go)

This my Go implementation,  but there is something wrong and in my debug don't show something, it is not showing anything that helps me to identify the problem :

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    v8 "rogchap.com/v8go"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("test")
    content, err := os.ReadFile("json-mask.js")
    fmt.Println(err)

    ctx := v8.NewContext()
    result, errorJS := ctx.RunScript(string(content), "file.js")
    
    fmt.Println(result)
    fmt.Println(errorJS)

    // the val returns null, I think I'm calling it wrong
    val, _ := ctx.RunScript("result", "value.js")

    fmt.Printf("addition result: %s", val)


}
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried in Go.  The `V8Go` lib seems pretty straight forward

Comment: Hey @JBirdVegas i put my code in GO. thanks.

Comment: Why don't you log the error returned from the second `RunScript` call where you're seeing an issue?

Comment: @Gavin It's not showing errors, it's resuming null. If I put anything in the second script it does not return an error and always returns null.

Comment: @MarceloMaico You're ignoring the error... `val, _ := ctx.RunScript("result", "value.js")` (`_` instead of `err`)

Comment: The result of error é "ReferenceError: result is not defined at value.js:1:1"  I tried all the file exports and even so it returns this error.

Comment: There is no global variable called `"result"` in your JS code, so from the JS side it will tell you there is a ReferenceError. One way to get a result is by adding `"let result = "` in front of the file content to hold the return value